# Monk heirloom pieces

Tags: world-of-warcraft

With MoP coming out soon enough, I was wondering if it's too early to prepare and have all of the required heirloom pieces for leveling a monk? I have justice points waiting to be spent and I'm not entirely sure which ones would best fit a monk in the upcoming release. Is this information known yet? Are we dealing with an unknown? If this data is available, what heirlooms should I pick up to prepare for a monk that I'd like to level in MoP?

Comment: It will probably share similar gear with druid (all three roles), as it is an agility based leather wearing class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data you request are indeed available, since the beta is already alive and kicking.

The monk will be a Leather wearing class, and in terms of Heirlooms it's going to share the gear with Rogues and Druids. Since you can be a DPS, a tank or even a healer, you have the following choiches (I've divided them in "healer/others"):

- **Head:** [Preened Tribal War Feathers](http://www.wowhead.com/item=61942)/[Stained Shadowcraft Cap](http://www.wowhead.com/item=61937)
- **Shoulders:** [Preened Ironfeather Shoulders](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42984)/[Stained Shadowcraft Shoulders](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42952)
- **Chest:** [Preened Ironfeather Chestplate](http://www.wowhead.com/item=48687)/[Stained Shadowcraft Tunic](http://www.wowhead.com/item=48689)
- **Cloak:** [Ancient Bloodmoon Cloak](http://www.wowhead.com/item=62040)/[Inherited Cape of the Black Baron](http://www.wowhead.com/item=62039)

For the weapons you can choose what you prefer. Monks will be able to use fist weapons, polearms, staves, 1h swords, 1h maces and 1h axes, with the ability to dual wield. As the Druids and Death Knights before them, they're going to be shieldless tanks.

- **Healer Weapons:** [Dignified Headmaster's Charge](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42947) (No good 1H+offhand alternatives, sorry)
- **Tank or DPS Weapons:** [Burnished Warden Staff](http://www.wowhead.com/item=79131). Added in 5.0.4, it's available from the heirloom vendor in Dalaran for 3500 Justice points. It's equivalent in terms of power to the [Repurposed Lava Dredger](http://www.wowhead.com/item=48718) (without the fire resistance), but it's been added specifically for the monks, that cannot wield 2h maces.

Comment: Devout Aurastone Hammer is a main hand weapon.  There's no heirloom offhand/shield to go with it unfortunately.

Comment: @Delameko thanks for the correction, I modified my answer

Comment: There is currently [a new staff](http://mop.wowhead.com/item=79131) available in mop beta

Comment: Np there is also legs from guild vendor now, but they require a mop guild achievement

Comment: http://www.wowhead.com/items=4.2?filter=qu=7;sl=7

Comment: Heal spec monks may not dual wield.  So my dual Devout Aurastone Hammer dream is crushed!

Comment: @DavidB even if you could dual wield, the Aurastone Hammer is MH only, as it has already been said... I'll remove that part of the answer, it's just confusing.