# What's the absolute fastest way to get a newly made monk to level 85 after Mists launches?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What's the absolute fastest (in terms of time spent after launch. Prep time pre-*Mists* is fine and can be discounted.) way to get a monk to level 85 and into relevant content when Mists comes out?

Use/abuse of XP bonuses from heirlooms, RAF, dual-boxing, etc. should all be considered fair-game here. Outright exploits and the hiring of third party players (aka power-levelling services) should not be.

Comment: Probably going to be the same game, RAF, heirlooms, and non-stop dungeon crawling with a higher level to quickly smash everything down.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this has been downvoted so much... Makes me kinda sad.

Comment: Probably because the "Monk" is arbitrary. Wouldn't the fastest way for the monk be the fastest way for everyone else (sans Death Knight) as well?

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's not really arbitrary though. The key thing here that distinguishes this from any other generic 'fastest levelling' question is the defined start time, with the functionally unlimited 'prep' time beforehand. I mean, I suppose you could say 'fastest way to get a $newclass to $level after an expansion' would be more generic, but using this language is substantially better SEO, among other things.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Right. But if you take out the "monk" aspect, it becomes more a thought excessive rather than any meaningful question: "What's the fastest possible way to get a character to 85 while minimizing their /played?"

Comment: @RavenDreamer You're right. When you take out the monk aspect it does become a thought exercise. Which is why it's relevant to the question, and worth including. It's also what makes it different from our existing 'How Do I Level Up Fast' questions. I'm just not entirely sure why that makes it arbitrary.

Comment: If not a duplicate, this question is at least strongly related to: ["How can I lquickly level up in WoW?"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/how-can-i-quickly-level-up-in-world-of-warcraft)

Comment: @Jeroen Certainly it's related. The key difference is the unlimited prep time offered. As you can see in Blems answer, the optimal solution here involves buying a second account and *leveling two more characters to 80*. That's hardly a reasonable answer to a standard question about leveling up quickly in WoW, even if the advice from those answers is *very* relevant to the 'home stretch' from 81 to 85.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## 1-80

Level 1-80 can be done in a couple of minutes, you can choose any race except Pandaran, they are forced to do there starting zone and choose fraction so they will not work for this.

On a side note Pandarans get the racial [Inner Peace](http://mop.wowhead.com/spell=107074), making their rested experience bonus last twice as long as normal. So a race change might be useful if you are not planing to go for max level in one go.

You will need to make a RAF account before MoP is released from your main account and use the RAF account to level up a combined 158 times. At least one character needs to reach level 80, so you'll need to buy WotLK for the second account as well. This will give you 79 levels to grant, so when you start your monk you can grant them all to your monk, instantly jumping to 80. There are a variety of ways to do this -  the simplest is to just level two characters from 1-80, and then one more to level 2, but the consensus for 'fastest' seems to be that only leveling one character to 80, and then bringing up a few characters to level 20 or 40. The only things to keep in mind is that at least one character needs to reach level 80, and you need a total of **79** grantable levels.

Additionally, you should keep in mind that your progress towards next level *as a percentage* is retained when levels are granted. This means that before granting the levels, you should take the 10 minutes to grind your Monk 99% of the way to level 2. After granting 79 levels, you'll be at level 80, and a single quest completion away from reaching level 81, which makes a nice head start heading into Hyjal.

You can read more on the specifics of the level granting process, as well as optimal dungeon runs and dual boxing techniques for banking grantable levels in [this thread at MMO-Champion.](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1175159-RAF-Monk-Level-Granting-The-Guide) In particular, you'll want to make sure to take advantage of the 300% XP bonus for keeping your 'veteran' and 'friend' accounts grouped at all times while doing this prep work.

## 81-85

There are 2 ways that can be recommended, Dungeon leveling or tagging.

They share some preparation that you need a bit of gear and a Guild:

### Gear

You will need heirloom that works for up to level 85, that is the helm and cloak, you can read more [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69150/monk-heirloom-pieces) on what heirlooms to get for a monk. Additionally, keep in mind that that your Monk is going to be wearing level 1 gear. Do yourself a favor and have a full set of Cataclysm-grade BoE's ready to go for your Monk before launch to keep yourself geared from 81-85.

### Guild

You need a level 6 guild for the Fast Track (Rank 2) perk that gives you 10% more XP. Higher level guild is recommended to make life easier and you will need a level 20 guild for the heirloom helm. More info on what perks you can get can be found [here](http://www.wowwiki.com/Guild_perks).

### Tagging

This consists of one playing attacking a monster and then one or more higher level player(s) killing the monster. The first player should receive full XP as long as the monster is not grey for the 2nd player. This can be very effective but can be mind numbingly boring, I have not done a lot of this so I cant recommend a place to do this, but what is important is the lower level player need to be able to attack the monster with out getting killed and there need to be a lot of monsters to kill, an example of a good place for horde players to do this can be seen below, as far as I can find this should still work(drops have been nerfed though) but I have not tested it:

Some level 80+ BoE gear would help the newly level 80 monk and a 2 person mount/guild summoning is also recommended.

### Dungeon leveling

This is what it sounds like, running dungeons until you hit 85. Killing mobs in dungeons gives good XP and you get bonus XP from completing dungeons when signing up with the dungeon finder.

For this you will need a full set level 80 BOE Cataclysm gear (ilevel is important), but the Helm and Cloak do not have to be useful, you just need them to boost your ilevel since heirloom gear is ilevel 1(or 0 I forget).

Some blue level 80-84 boe items that a monk can equip(not necessarily useful, could be cloth) would also be recommended to make sure you keep your ilevel up even if you get unlucky with dungeon drops.

I would recommend running this as a full group(tank, healer and 3 dps) or at least tank+healer combo(the monk can be either of them if needed) to make sure you get instant queues. You can also do this with higher level chars(level 85 in full raid gear) to speed up the dungeon clearing.

Comment: Congrats on an inevitable Reversal badge I guess.

Comment: I think other combinations than 2*level 80 can be used for the RAF. At least 1 need to be 80, the other one just need to be able to grant 39 levels and have at least 1 char at 41, so you could save 1 copy of WotLK, but I think it would be easier just to level 3 chars together to 80.

Comment: you only need one RAF account to bank enough levels, regardless. I've done some editing to refine and clarify that portion.

Comment: This seems general enough to be an answer for our general [fastest way to level in WoW question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/how-can-i-quickly-level-up-in-world-of-warcraft).

Comment: @marktrapp except for the fact that the amount of prep work involved makes this method extremely time consuming and inappropriate as an answer to that question. But we've already had that argument.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz good update, i thought the 39 levels it says in [the guide](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/recruit-a-friend-rewards#5) was a cap pr account, but guess it is just pr char.

Comment: So you bank the levels across the account and not per character?  Could I level up 8 characters to 20, and then transfer an 80 from one of my other accounts to do the granting?

Comment: @Delameko I am pretty sure it is pr char, so you will need to swap chars to grant the levels, but you can grant from multiple chars from the RAF account to one char on main account

Comment: @Blem Your response has gotten me pretty amped at the idea of so many bonus levels to give away. Any advice on the best/easiest way to use multiple accounts? Just plain ol' autofollow and alt-tab?

Comment: I haven't done it yet, but it seems like the easiest way is going with 3 accounts, your main account and 2 Raf accounts. Linking them main account > RaF A and RaF A > RaF B. Create new chars on RaF accounts and boost the RaF accounts with a high level from your main account by soloing dungeons. Once you have a level 80 on each RaF account, you take your RaF B account and boost a new char from your main account and RaF A account the same way up to level 41. Your RaF B account can now grant your level 41 on RaF A account 39 levels and you got 2 level 80 on RaF A to grand your main account.

Comment: @TerranceShaw atm I am running 3 elemental shammys at the same time, it is relative easy to set up so you can control all 3 using a free program called hotkeynet, an addon called Jamba and ingame macros. If you want to spend money you can also buy some programs that do most of the out of game work for you instead of hotkeynet.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from Refer a Friend, you can actually level to 85 pretty quickly from the guild perks and BoA gear.  There's a bit more of a gold investment in game this way compared to spending money irl, but it's another options.  There are leveling guides all over the place, but I found one on wowhead that was Monk specific (item lists, enchants to get, where to get food, etc).

My monk is at 77 and climbing...

http://www.wowhead.com/guide=1266/monk-to-85-in-3-days-played